# Delete client with newline in name

Tags: chef-infra, knife

Ok, so this started because I was trying to get auto-scaled nodes to self register with Chef.  I had the following in my `client.rb` file:

```
node_name "some_prefix-#{`hostname`}"
```

the idea was that each node would have the same prefix but a hostname based suffix.  Sadly, `hostname` returns a string with a `\n` on the end of it.  Chef happily let me create this client, but it is unable to actually access it in any way.

```
knife client show some_prefix-myHostname
knife client show "some_prefix-myHostname\n"
knife client show "some_prefix-myHostname%0A"
```

all three result in a 404

```
knife client list
```

does show the client, and a blank newline after it.

I have fixed my client.rb template, but I can't get rid of the nodes I created with the newline in their names.  I've tried using knife, the webui, and even manually using the Chef::REST library in irb, but everything results in a 404.

Any ideas?

EDIT:
I have also tried `knife client bulk delete` but that fails as well.  It appears that the REST library sanitizes the url and removes the newline before attempting to send the request.

Comment: Ideas from top of my head: `knife client show 'some_prefix-myHostname\n'` (single quote to avoid interpolation in the library). Or trying to double escape it like `knife client show 'some_prefix-myHostname\\n'` ?

Comment: Could you key off of something else?  For example, \s$ I believe will match everything that ends in any kind of whitespace.  Do you have clients that you want to keep that end in whitespace?

Comment: No, these were just an accident that I can't seem to get rid of.  But  no amount of matching will help.  The code will get the list, iterate through to check for a match, and then try to send a REST request to delete each node.  The matching all happens client side, and the final request to actually delete fails.   I suspect it is because the URI parser will strip the newline.

Comment: I had the same issue some time ago. Forgot to strip `hostname`. The only thing that may work in this case is logging into the database yourself and fixing the client. I did not want to do that, it was easier for me to reinstall Chef server, because I have the whole configuration (including nodes and clients) in repository.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using [knife raw](https://docs.chef.io/knife_raw.html) which lets you send requests directly to the Chef Server API

```
knife raw /nodes/<node-name>
knife raw delete -m /nodes/<node-name>
```

This worked for me on a similar issue with an invalid role name.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known [bug](https://github.com/chef/chef-server/issues/124) in the chef-server. I wasn't able to verify it - on my current server-version (12) an error gets triggered:

```
Chef::Exceptions::ValidationFailed: Option name's value test\n does not match regular expression /^[\-[:alnum:]_\.]+$/
```

**But** you might be able to use the [chef-API](https://docs.chef.io/api_chef_server.html) to revert this by hand, as described (the other way round) in the bug-report above:

```
chef > api.get("/clients").keys
=> ["acme-validator", "some_prefix-myHostname\n"]
chef > api.put("/clients/some_prefix-myHostname\n", name: "some_prefix-myHostname"); nil   
=> nil
chef > api.get("/clients").keys
=> ["acme-validator", "some_prefix-myHostname"]
```

I felt free to already reorder the statements and replace "foobar" by "some_prefix-myHostname".

I guess also, using the API should let you delete the client by hand:

```
api.delete("/clients/some_prefix-myHostname\n")
```

Comment: thanks for the idea.  Sadly, the other way around does not work.  The rest endpoint can't contain a '/n', only the the json data can.  :(

Comment: Huhm.. thats sad.. :(

Comment: @TejayCardon - the only idea i have left is: doing a `knife download`to backup all the stuff you want to hold, do a `chef-server-ctl cleanse` to remove all data (this step will require a `reconfigure` afterwards - i havent used it so far), and then put your stuff back online with `knife upload`. I used these steps to move from hosted chef to the community-version.

Comment: Yea, that might do it.  I even tried manually generating the URI and passing that to the UI, but then the server threw an error.  I think I'm going to have to go into the database to fix it.  But we're probably going to start with a clean server for Chef 12 in a month or two, so I may just not bother.

Comment: I'm sorry that i wasn't a help and good luck with tweaking the database.

Comment: thanks for the attempt.  Not your fault there wasn't a right answer to be found.  Your ideas were great.